# My question was answered already, but the wrong duplicate was used

Tags: support

I flagged my own question as a duplicate when an answer pointed out another question that had already answered it - but someone else had suggested a different duplicate, and the duplicate flagged for my question was *that* one, instead of the one I'd flagged it as.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43895361) is my question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14677993) is the question I wanted to mark my question as a duplicate of.

Is there any way to change which question my question is a duplicate of?  Or is it stuck like this now?

Comment: It's been added as an additional dupe target

Comment: @JonClements So it has!  Though I'm still curious if there's something I could have done myself.

Comment: I don't believe so unless you have a gold badge in any of the tags on the question. Gold badge holders can edit the duplicate target list.

Comment: Yeah, we get all the fun toys. :-)

Answer (score 19):

You can either ping the gold badge holder (provided it was [dupehammered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders)) or mod flag to have this added (as those are the only two groups that can do this)

[Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

I would suggest just deleting it if it has no answers, however, as [the Roomba script will delete it otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: unfortunately theres an asnwer on the question

Comment: @WhatsThePoint For this one, yes. Am explaining for future reference, or others who find this.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers were already listed in the duplicates box. I've moved your preferred one to the top of the list.